# Como comparar domicilios de dos bases en MySQL?

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

Tengo dos bases con domicilios. Tengo que traer resultados donde los domicilios sean igual o similares, ya que como son tablas tipeadas por personas una calle puede estar escrita de distintas maneras, ejemplo: "Avenida Rivadavia 456" y "Av. Rivadavia 456"
Se me ocurrió usar LIKE pero no se como escribir los % cuando hay un campo

Comment: Prueba con `LOCATE()` y nos cuentas qué tal

Comment: Para casos como este, no es ocioso considerar la [distancia de Levenshtein](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distancia_de_Levenshtein).

Comment: puedes poner lo que has intentado es decir parte del codigo